# Concept of calling a CI framework externally from another site

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

HELP,Im lost.

What is the concept of calling a CI framework PHP from another site?
Do I need any plugins to help me achieving it?
Must I use a CI to call a CI and how do I cURL that? 
Is it the input data problem for POST DATA?

I cURL-ed the website but theres no response since I cant get the CI controller to function.

I have tried XML, string,JSON, but it doesnt work.

I have read Requests,Rest Server https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver.

If there's any good reference about this, please share it .

I have got the captcha using CURL.
but when I tried to post the postData into the login page,
The web page isnot responding. I wonder if the controller didnt receive any post data.

```
 $postdata1 = "aid=" . urlencode($log["userlogin"]) . "&apw=" . urlencode($log["passlogin"]) . "&code=" . urlencode($captcha) . "&submitlogin=Login!";

 echo $postdata1;

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"$site/index.php/admin");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.7) Gecko/20091221 Firefox/3.5.7");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd() . $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd() . $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result1 = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

TAMPER DATA RESULT:

`//POSTDATA=aid=admin&apw=admin&code=1272&submitlogin=Login!`

UPDATE:
AFter meddling for hours, I finally got into the controller function .
    `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"$site/index.php/admin/login");`

admin. php function login();

Answer (score 0):

Okay. so after some few hours, I managed to find out the solution.

It doesnt matter what kind of ways we are using to cURL a page.
I'm choosing the old method like the one above.

To call a function in CI Controller . we can do it like this. 
For example I want to access login.

`curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"$site/index.php/admin/login");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.7) Gecko/20091221 Firefox/3.5.7");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd() . $cookie);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd() . $cookie);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result1 = curl_exec ($ch);`

if I want to send more parameters just add it to the URL according to the function parameter in Controller.

eg.

Controller.php 
`function editpw($adminid,$password){}`

`curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"$site/index.php/admin/editpw/$adminid/$password");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.7) Gecko/20091221 Firefox/3.5.7");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd() . $cookie);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd() . $cookie);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $result1 = curl_exec ($ch);`

There you go.